# spacy.matcher.PhraseMatcher object has no attribute "remove"

Tags: spacy

I studied spacy at link https://spacy.io/api/phrasematcher#remove. I copy it to jupyter like this

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
from spacy import displacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
phraseMatcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab)
phraseMatcher.add("OBAMA", [nlp("Barack Obama")])
assert "OBAMA" in phraseMatcher
phraseMatcher.remove("OBAMA")
assert "OBAMA" not in phraseMatcher
```

But I got the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-a5e1de7c4514> in <module>
      2 phraseMatcher.add("OBAMA", [nlp("Barack Obama")])
      3 assert "OBAMA" in phraseMatcher
----> 4 phraseMatcher.remove("OBAMA")
      5 assert "OBAMA" not in phraseMatcher

AttributeError: 'spacy.matcher.PhraseMatcher' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

I searched but didn't get any ideas why, anyone can show where my mistakes :(

This is my screen shoot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PhraseMatcher.remove` was added in spacy v2.2 (https://v2.spacy.io/api/phrasematcher#remove). Maybe you are using an older version?